# "There" as an adverb

Tags: adverbs

In sentences like, "*there* is a great place down the street," and "*there* is no reason to do that," *there* is being used as an adverb, and OED defines this particular usage as:

> ADVERB 
>   
>     (usually **there is/are**) Used to indicate the fact or existence of something:
>   *there’s a restaurant round the corner
>
>   there comes a point where you give up*

My question is, what exactly is it modifying?

Also, if it's modifying *is/are*, then doesn't *is* indicate the fact of existence well enough on its own?

---

Edit: Is it just a kind of there-support to avoid writing a sentence like, " a restaurant around the corner is"?

Comment: I'm not sure it's modifying anything, any more than it's modifying anything in the sentence "The bus stop is there."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not an adverb, nor a locative of any sort, but a 'dummy' pronoun, without reference. Its sole function is to act as the subject of a sentence asserting the existence of the 'complement' of the verb *BE* - as you suggest, it is the idiomatic way of expressing "A restaurant around the corner is".